# How can I load another page from inside php tags that's inside an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Using `ajax`, I'm loading table values through `php`. My problem is that when an error occurs and is sent to `php` function `mail_error()` for processing, the `error.html` page is loaded inside the working document instead of redirecting.

```
function mail_error($ex) {
  $from = "error@mysite.co";
  $to = "error@mysite.co";
  $subject = "ERROR!";
  $message = $ex."\n\nwith user: ".$_SESSION['memberid'];
  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  header("Location: error.html");
}
```

Is there a way to change that last line so that it redirects to `error.html`?

Here's the `JQuery` that calls the `php`:

```
$.ajax({
        url     : 'wsviewattendance.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        async   : true,
        data    : {
                    'fetch' : 1,
                    'limit' : view,
                    'id'    : nameid
        },
        success:function(re){
           $('#showdata').html(re); 

                $.ajax({
                        url     : 'wsviewattendance.php',
                        type    : 'POST',
                        async   : true,
                        data    : {
                                    'setheading'    : 1
                        },
                        success:function(re){
                            if(re == "1"){
                                return false;
                            } else {
                               $('#showheading').html(re);
                            }
                        }   

                });                         
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have to change jQuery script

Comment: Can you paste your script part ?

Comment: @fusion3k - i tried that, and it worked. Thing is that I have over 50 pages with over 500 plus `ajax` calls to make this change to. So if I can do it from within that one line in the `mail_error()` function, then that's the way I'd like to go.

Comment: Sure you can change the php script, but if the jQuery script load the result in working document the result of php script will be printed in the working document...

Comment: @fusion3k - Thanks for your input. I'd tried your suggestion before I made this post, and it worked fine. I'm just cringing at all the `ajax` calls that need to be changed. Sometimes, though, you have to grab the hammer and start swinging with what you have.